# Use LINQ to Group data from data table

Tags: vb.net, linq, grouping

I have a linq  question. I want to use LINQ to group data from a DataTable (columns: RUN_NAME,H_YYYY,H_MM,H_MON).

The data looks like this:

| RUN_NAME | H_YYYY | H_MM | H_MON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-1 | 2019 | 1 | Jan |
| 2019-1 | 2019 | 2 | Feb |
| 2019-1 | 2019 | 3 | Mar |
| 2019-1 | 2019 | 4 | Apr |
| 2019-2 | 2019 | 5 | May |
| 2019-2 | 2019 | 6 | Jun |
| 2019-2 | 2019 | 7 | Jul |
| 2019-2 | 2019 | 8 | Aug |
| 2019-3 | 2019 | 9 | Sep |
| 2019-3 | 2019 | 10 | Oct |
| 2019-3 | 2019 | 11 | Nov |
| 2019-3 | 2019 | 12 | Dec |

I need something like this in the result where the individual run details are grouped as part of a each run (2019-1, 2019-2, 2019-3):

2019-1

```
  2019 1 Jan

  2019 2 Feb

  2019 3 Mar

  2019 4 Apr
```

2019-2

```
  2019 5 May

  2019 6 Jun

  2019 7 Jul

  2019 8 Aug
```

2019-3

```
  2019 9 Sep

  2019 10 Oct

  2019 11 Nov

  2019 12 Dec
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    CalendarMonthList = (From rw As DataRow In dt.Rows Select New CalendarMonth With {
                                                                                  .Run_Name=CheckStringNull(rw("run_name").ToString),
.Month_Scope = (From r In dt.AsEnumerable Where r("run_name") = .Run_Name Select New MonthScope With {.h_yyyy = CheckDbNull(rw("h_yyyy")), 
.h_mm=CheckDbNull(rw("h_mm")),
.h_mon=CheckStringNull(rw("h_mon").ToString)}).Distinct.ToList()}).Distinct.ToList()
```

where my definition of the CalendarMonth is as below:

```
Public Class CalendarMonth
        Public Property Run_Name As String
        Public Property Month_Scope As List(Of MonthScope)
End Class
```

and my definition of MonthScope Class is as below:

```
Public Class MonthScope
        Public Property h_yyyy As Integer?
        Public Property h_mm As Integer?
        Public Property h_mon As String
End Class
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? What result does your code provide and how does that differ from your expectation?

Comment: Do you really want to group or are you just trying to sort? I see no evidence of any attempt to group in your code so obviously no grouping will occur. If you really want to group then you should read up on how to group using LINQ and then make an attempt to implement what you learn, then post a question about that if it doesn't work.

Comment: There's a grouping example [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/linq-vbnet) to get you started. That was halfway down the first page of results in a search for "vb.net linq group".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my take on it is your "i need something like this" is a representation of the objects you want; 3 CalendarMonth each with a populated Month_Scope list, which are MonthScopes (4 of them)

First, I'd really like to tweak your classes a bit, for one - to remove the dodgy property names and for two - to add a couple of constructors that will construct the class from a datarow. You could structure this some other way if you like (e.g. shared FromDataRow method or factory), or you could merge this logic back into your LINQ statement if you want.. I did it as constructors because I feel it keeps it cleaner and on-point to have it that way:

```
Public Class CalendarMonth
    Public Property RunName As String
    Public Property MonthScopes As New List(Of MonthScope)

    Public Sub New(rn As String, ms As IEnumerable(Of DataRow))
        RunName = rn
        MonthScopes = ms.Select(Function(msro) New MonthScope(msro)).ToList()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MonthScope
    Public Property Yyyy As Integer?
    Public Property MM As Integer?
    Public Property Mon As String

    Public Sub New(ms As DataRow)
        If Not ms.IsNull("h_yyyy") Then Yyyy = CInt(ms("h_yyyy"))
        If Not ms.IsNull("h_mm") Then MM = CInt(ms("h_mm"))
        If Not ms.IsNull("h_mon") Then Mon = CStr(ms("h_mon"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you have a LINQ statement of, which is a lot nicer:

```
    Dim calendarMonthList = dt.AsEnumerable() _
        .GroupBy(Function(r) CStr(r("run_name"))) _
        .Select(Function(g) New CalendarMonth(g.Key, g)) _
        .ToList()
```

Comment: Perfect ! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Much appreciated. LINQ newbie here.